# How to use join in my case Postgres query ?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.1, self-join

i am trying to get product's `name` and `categ_id`. I have two tables that are,

```
product_template

categ_id     name
7            Nokia classic
7            Nokia lumia
8            samsung s3
6            huawai
```

this table have `product` that i want to get,

```
product_category

id       name         parent_id   
6        phones       3
7        nokia        6
8        samsung      6
```

this table shows that which product is under `phone > nokia` and `phone > samsung` or product can be directly under phone as shown under,

like,

```
phones > huawai
phones > nokia   > Nokia classic
phones > nokia   > Nokia lumia
phones > samsung > samsung s3
```

query i am using is,

```
select pt.categ_id,pt.name from product_template pt inner join product_category pc on
pt.categ_id=pc.id where pc.parent_id='6'
```

it is showing all products except `huawai` ???

query should run like that it can get products that are under `phone` directly and under this way `phone > nokia > Nokia Classic`

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to fetch only the templates under a category, and the templates under that category's children categories, use that query:

```
select pt.categ_id, pt.name
from product_template pt
inner join product_category pc on pt.categ_id = pc.id
where '6' in (pc.id, pc.parent_id)
```

But that selects only templates within 1 level range of the selected category. If you want to select all descendant categories' templates, you can use the [recursive common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with recursive rpc(id) AS (
    select '3'::int
  union all
    select id
    from product_category pc
    where pc.parent_id = rpc.id
)
select pt.categ_id, pt.name
from product_template pt
inner join rpc on pt.categ_id = rpc.id
```